# CSS Transitions with repeating backgrounds

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

So this animation exists:

https://codepen.io/NickyCDK/pen/AIonk

```
body { background-color:#333; }
#snow{
    background: none;
    font-family: Androgyne;
    background-image: url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img/s1.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s2.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s3.png');
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 400px 1000px, 200px 400px, 100px 300px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
```

And I wanted to use it for a full background, however it is causing browser lag. So I converted it over to use transform to lessen the resources needed. However I am running into an issue where it is no longer repeating the background infinitely and I'm not sure how to resolve this using the transform functionality. I have two snippits I've tried and have been unable to figure out the answer to, and am wondering if this is even possible or if I'm going in the right direction with either.

https://jsfiddle.net/psa5pgbe/

```
#snow-l, #snow-m, #snow-s {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#snow-l:before, #snow-m:before, #snow-s:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#snow-l:before {
    animation: snow-l 100s linear infinite;
    background: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-l-c.png") 0 0 repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-l {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(2500px, 5000px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(5000px, 10000px);
}
}

#snow-m:before {
    animation: snow-m 100s linear infinite;
    background: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-m-c.png") 0 0 repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-m {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(1000px, 2000px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(2000px, 4000px);
}
}

#snow-s:before {
    animation: snow-s 100s linear infinite;
    background: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-s-c.png") 0 0 repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-s {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(-1000px, 1500px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(-1000px, 3000px);
}
}
```

This first one is using pseudo selectors.

https://jsfiddle.net/aLLuj7ah/

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#snow * {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#snow-l {
    animation: snow-l 10s linear infinite;
    background-image: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-l-c.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-l {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(500px, 500px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(500px, 1000px);
}
}

#snow-m {
    animation: snow-m 10s linear infinite;
    background-image: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-m-c.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-m {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(100px, 200px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(200px, 400px);
}
}

#snow-s {
    animation: snow-s 10s linear infinite;
    background-image: url("https://static1.xenogamers.com/styles/default/xenogamers/christmas/snow-s-c.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
@keyframes snow-s {
0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
50% {
    transform: translate(-100px, 150px);
}
100% {
    transform: translate(-100px, 300px);
}
}
```

The second one is not and more simplified.

Is either going in the right direction or is this simply not possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I think transform will also lag as what i see is that instead of changing background position, you are changing the container position using translate but still using animate which is the reason for the lag.

Comment: @NasirT is it possible to change the background position with transform?

Comment: Working on a solution. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @NasirT what would the solution be then since I'm not sure how this could be done with transform.

Comment: There are 2 or 3 options. One you can use transition property with hover on the #snow div to change the background-position from 0 px setting to the max setting you can copy from the 100% keyframe. Second you can use the html5 canvas to design this animation in jquery/js. Third you can use just jquery animate function to change the background infinitely. We would have to test and research to check which one will not impact heavily on the browser. But do note that any animation puts some graphical load on the browser as your are playing with pixel changes dynamically.

Comment: The issue with transition is that you cannot loop it. The issue with canvas is you will have to come up with a logic and complex mathematical formulas to keep the animation. E.g. Here is a confetti code i worked with another dev to help him out and it contains alot of complex formulas. ( http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/vyOvxL ) The third option is basically the same as css but it will be using javascript rather than the browser to keep tabs. This actually can help a bit. Still i may be wrong here so you need to research this a bit.